# Display gridview in combobox dropdown. C#

Tags: c#, combobox

Is there any way in c# to display gridview in combobox dropdown? When user clicks on combobox, instead of dropdown I want to display gridview with multiple rows and columns at the bottom of combobox.

Comment: Are you using WinForms? WPF? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do this. You cannot change the drop down to act the way you want. You should create your own control.

Here is the steps you need to do:

- Create a user control consisting of a text area and a button (like a usual ComboBox). You can also use these methods to draw your control exactly like a ComboBox:

  ComboBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, ComboBoxState state);
  ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, ComboBoxState state);

Then you need to show a drop down containing your ListView, after uses clicks the button. You can use this component for the drop down part:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17502/Simple-Popup-Control

I have done such thing a few years ago. I need some time to convert it to a CodeProject article!

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=(local);DataBase=RIMS;User Id=sa;Password=Rootdb");
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from Master_City", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "city");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "city";

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
col.HeaderText = "Name";
col.Name = "Name";
col.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
col.DisplayMember = ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ToString();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```